# Would this be the correct number of child processes created?

Tags: c, fork

I've got that the total no. of child processes created is 6 but I'm not quite sure if this is correct. If it's incorrect can someone point me towards the right direction. I've inserted a rough sketch of how I received the answer.

```
void main() {
  int pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0)
    fork();
  pid = fork();
  if(pid != 0)
    fork();
  exit(0);
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you put a pause() before the exit(0), you will be able to see the process tree with "ps" or "pstree"... from another terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should end up with 9 processes in the end.

```
int main() {            //  |
  int pid = fork();     //  +-----+
  if(pid == 0)          //  |     |
    fork();             //        +-----+
  pid = fork();         //  +---+ +---+ +---+
  if(pid != 0)          //  |   | |   | |   |
    fork();             //  +-+   +-+   +-+
  return 0;             //  | | | | | | | | |
}
```

In `int pid = fork();` you double the amount of processes where `pid == 0` in one case and  `pid != 0` in the other case. One of them is doubled again two lines later. So after the first part you have 3 processes in total.

from `pid = fork();` on it does'nt patter whether the processes were parent or child, because you reassign `pid`. In this 2nd part you triple the total amount again, so you end up with 9 processes in total.

In 3 of them `pid = fork();` returned 0, 6 of them (the child processes from this line and from the last `fork()`) have `pid != 0`.

Comment: So would that mean that 3 of them are the child process and 6 are the parent due to child processes returning 0?

Comment: 1 of them is only parent all others are child. But 2 of the child processes are parents as well. So only 6 of them are "pure" child. Processes can be child and parent at the same time. child = created by other, parent = creates other.

Comment: Ahh that makes perfect sense, really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I added pause() at the end of the main():

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void) {
  int pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0)
    fork();
  pid = fork();
  if(pid != 0)
    fork();
  pause();
  exit(0);
}
```

I compiled and executed it. In another terminal, I used [pstree](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pstree.1.html):

```
$ pstree -p -h 11052
a.out(11052)-+-a.out(11053)-+-a.out(11056)-+-a.out(11058)
             |              |              `-a.out(11060)
             |              |-a.out(11057)
             |              `-a.out(11059)
             |-a.out(11054)
             `-a.out(11055)
```